# Drag&Drop Cut to List Box

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, listbox

I want to drag a listbox item to another listbox. **I want to cut items, not copy.**

But **if I drag item to the same listbox**, item copies itself in this listbox.

How can I prevent it?

```
namespace dragdrop
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.listBox1.DragEnter += new System.Windows.Forms.DragEventHandler(this.listBox1_DragEnter);
            this.listBox2.DragOver += new System.Windows.Forms.DragEventHandler(this.listBox2_DragOver);
            this.listBox1.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.listBox1_MouseDown);
            this.listBox2.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.listBox2_MouseDown);
            this.listBox2.DragDrop += new System.Windows.Forms.DragEventHandler(this.listBox2_DragDrop);
            this.listBox1.DragDrop += new System.Windows.Forms.DragEventHandler(this.listBox1_DragDrop);
        }

        private void listBox1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
        }

        private void listBox2_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyState == 1)
            {
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
            }
        }

        private void listBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Point sonnokta = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
            int item_index = listBox1.IndexFromPoint(sonnokta);
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                listBox1.DoDragDrop(listBox1.Items[item_index], DragDropEffects.Move);
            }
        }

        private void listBox2_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Point sonnokta = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
            int item_index = listBox2.IndexFromPoint(sonnokta);
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                listBox2.DoDragDrop(listBox2.Items[item_index], DragDropEffects.Move);
            }
        }

        private void listBox2_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            listBox2.Items.Add(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text));
            listBox1.Items.Remove(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text));
        }

        private void listBox1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text));
            listBox2.Items.Remove(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check if the item already exists in the current ListBox:

```
private void listBox2_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e) {
  string dragItem = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text) as string;
  if (dragItem != null && !listBox2.Items.Contains(dragItem)) {
    listBox2.Items.Add(dragItem);
    listBox1.Items.Remove(dragItem);
  }
}

private void listBox1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e) {
  string dragItem = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text) as string;
  if (dragItem != null && !listBox1.Items.Contains(dragItem)) {
    listBox1.Items.Add(dragItem);
    listBox2.Items.Remove(dragItem);
  }
}
```